# Extend Ruby String class with method to change the contents

Tags: ruby

I am trying to extend the ruby string class like this:

```
String.class_eval do
  def clear!
    # Here I want the string value to be set to empty string. The following code is not working.
    self = ''
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001144):

```
class String
  def clear!
    replace ""
  end
end

x = "foo"
x.clear!
p x
#=> ""
```

*Similarly available: [`Array#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000262) and [`Hash#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000757).*

Alternatively, and far less cleanly:

```
class String
  def clear!
    gsub! /.+/m, ''
  end
end

class String
  def clear!
    slice!(0,-1)
  end
end

# ...and so on; use any mutating method to set the contents to ""
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
String.class_eval do
  def clear!
    self[0..-1] = ""
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As counter-intuitive as it seems, I think you should be using String.instance_eval because what you want is a class method:
http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/01/09/fun-with-rubys-instance_eval-and-class_eval/

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
class String
  alias_method :clear!, :clear
end
```

Although I'm not sure what your `String#clear!` provides over the existing [`String#clear`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/String%3aclear) method.